# How to speed up copying files between two accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to copy some buckets from one account to another. I got all permissions so I started transferring the data via cli (cp command). I am operating on a c4.large. The problem is that there is pretty much data (9tb) and it goes realy slow. In 20 minutes I transferred like 20gb...
I checked the internet speed and the download is 3000Mbit/s and the upload is 500 Mbit/s. How can I speed up it?

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command simply sends the copy request to Amazon S3. The data is transferred between the Amazon S3 buckets without downloading to your computer. Therefore, the size and bandwidth of the computer issuing the command is not related to the speed of data transfer.

It is likely that the `aws s3 cp` command is only copying a small number of files simultaneously. You could increase the speed by setting the `max_concurrent_requests` parameter to a higher value:

```
aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 20
```

See:

- [AWS CLI S3 Configuration — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)
- [Getting the Most Out of the Amazon S3 CLI | AWS Partner Network (APN) Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-the-most-out-of-the-amazon-s3-cli/)